# change button while pressing it with vue.js

Tags: button, vue.js, onclick

Basically what i want to do is clicking my button and immediately hide this button and make appear another.

My two buttons are:

```
<button @click="" value="Add to favorites" style="font-weight: 700;color:#428bca;margin-left:30px;height:30px;border-radius:4px" name="favorites">Add to favorites</button>

<button @click="" value="Delete from favorites" style="font-weight: 700;color:#428bca;margin-left:30px;height:30px;border-radius:4px" name="delete" v-if="show">Delete from favorites</button>
```

Please i need a solution only with vue.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can condition the exibition of each `button` through a property [**via `v-show`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show). (In the demos below, the `isFavorite` property is being used.)

Then, in the `click` events you can change such property.

Either change it **directly** in the `@click`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFavorite: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="isFavorite = true" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="isFavorite = false" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>
</div>
```

Or change it **via a method**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFavorite: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite() {
      this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>
</div>
```

Or, if you think it'd improve the readability of your code, using **multiple methods**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFavorite: false
  },
  methods: {
    addToFavorites() {
      this.isFavorite = true;
    },
    deleteFromFavorites() {
      this.isFavorite = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addToFavorites" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="deleteFromFavorites" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>
</div>
```

Comment: One more question, how would yoy insert two functions on the @click=""?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209834/how-to-add-two-functions-on-a-click-event-using-vue-js/49210431#49210431 (I was the one answering that one, btw :)

Comment: and lets suppose i dont want to appear the button "Add to favorites" when refreshing the page, and instead i want to appear the one that is already pick

Comment: for example you click on the button "add to favorites" and it shows you the delete button and when refreshing the page, it has to still show you that button

Comment: That is a matter of saving (and loading) the `isFavorite` data somewhere. The buttons will act according to its value.

Comment: I save data on my mysql database

Comment: and i did if (favorite = 1) then show delete with php, but then the functions you gave me stop working well

Comment: i just wanted to know if there exist any functions that knows what button was lately showed

Comment: Don't manipulate the template (the `<html>` part). Have PHP set the `data` part. Something like: `new Vue({ el: '#app', data: {
    isFavorite: <?= $favorite == 1 ? 'true' : 'false ?>
  }, /* ... */ }`

Comment: im going to make a question, i hope you can give me some examples! i tried what you said and it always give the delete button, i bet im doing something wrong, Thanks

Comment: This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213928/dont-get-changes-while-refreshing-the-page-with-vue-js

Comment: Add there the PHP code that generates the page. You'll need some server-side changes.

Comment: Yess!! it worked, thank you very much. In a few hours i'll be doing image upload with php and javascript. Hope we keep in touch!

Comment: @acdcjunior I use your second solution but I have multiple buttons on the same page so it is toggling ALL of my buttons text. How do I localize it to individual buttons?

Answer (score 0):

my perefered way:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

function buttonClickEventListener(e) {
  e.target.innerText = "clicked";
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="buttonClickEventListener">Click On Me</button>
</template>
```

however it's a combination of vue and vanilla js and has a mixed up logic. you can use inline class and style if you prefer "best practice".