# Localize Button click events on page using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple buttons a page and when I click one to toggle the buttons text, ALL of the buttons change. How do I use VUE to separate functionality and individualize each buttons `@click` to only affect the clicked button? In the snippet below you will see that all buttons change on click. I only want the clicked buttons text to change.

See example below. This example is from another post and all credit goes to:

[change button while pressing it with vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211418/change-button-while-pressing-it-with-vue-js)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFavorite: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite() {
      this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>
 <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary (object) instead of a single variable:

```js
data() {
  return {
    isFavorite: {}
  }
},
```

Instead of toggling a single boolean, toggle a property on the object:

```html
<button @click="toggleFavorite('item1')" v-show="!isFavorite['item1']">Add to favorites</button>
<button @click="toggleFavorite('item1')" v-show="isFavorite['item1']">Delete from favorites</button>
```

The toggle:

```js
methods: {
  toggleFavorite(item) {
    this.$set(this.isFavorite, item, !this.isFavorite[item]);
  }
}
```

Demo if this is still unclear:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isFavorite: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite(item) {
      this.$set(this.isFavorite, item, !this.isFavorite[item]);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleFavorite('item100')" v-show="!isFavorite['item100']">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite('item100')" v-show="isFavorite['item100']">Delete from favorites</button>

  <button @click="toggleFavorite('item101')" v-show="!isFavorite['item101']">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite('item101')" v-show="isFavorite['item101']">Delete from favorites</button>
  
  <hr>
  
  <div v-for="x in 10" :key="x">
    <button @click="toggleFavorite(`item${x}`)" v-show="!isFavorite[`item${x}`]">Add to favorites</button>
    <button @click="toggleFavorite(`item${x}`)" v-show="isFavorite[`item${x}`]">Delete from favorites</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the v-show values are same. I think this implementation is the not best practise for Vue. You can use v-if v-else for data value  or just change the text by value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFavorite: false,
    isFavorite2:false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite() {
      this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    },
    toggleFavorite2() {
      this.isFavorite2 = !this.isFavorite2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="!isFavorite">Add to favorites</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite" v-show="isFavorite">Delete from favorites</button>

<button @click="toggleFavorite2" v-show="!isFavorite2">Add to favorites 2</button>
  <button @click="toggleFavorite2" v-show="isFavorite2">Delete from favorites 2</button>
</div>
```